# Android/Java Parse anonymous JSONArray object

Tags: java, android, json, arrays, anonymous

**Duplicate of** [Get JSONArray without array name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164741/get-jsonarray-without-array-name)

Server is returning me the following anonymous JSONArray, I don't know how to parse it. Please help me in parsing it. I am not using any library like Gson, I am using `org.json.JSONObject`. Pleaes help.

```
[
        {
            "provider_metadata": {
                "filename": "vr-banner-small.png"
            },
            "name": "vr-banner-small.png",
            "enabled": false,
            "provider_name": "sonata.media.provider.image",
            "provider_status": 1,
            "provider_reference": "1debc89fa2a4a54599c48ba13f9ccfe1ff7c2360.png",
            "width": 183,
            "height": 122,
            "context": "default",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-18T22:54:50+0800",
            "created_at": "2014-04-18T22:54:50+0800",
            "content_type": "image/png",
            "size": 42117,
            "id": 190
        },
        {
            "provider_metadata": {
                "filename": "Chrysanthemum.jpg"
            },
            "name": "中文名稱.png",
            "enabled": false,
            "provider_name": "sonata.media.provider.image",
            "provider_status": 1,
            "provider_reference": "2d2ea78282c45fac7c7a3b3e37c77b92b05850cb.jpeg",
            "width": 1024,
            "height": 768,
            "context": "default",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-19T03:16:53+0800",
            "created_at": "2014-04-18T22:59:11+0800",
            "content_type": "image/jpeg",
            "size": 879394,
            "id": 191
        },
        {
            "provider_metadata": {
                "filename": "1111.jpg"
            },
            "name": "1111.jpg",
            "enabled": false,
            "provider_name": "sonata.media.provider.image",
            "provider_status": 1,
            "provider_reference": "605e5a4ec678546d780a72ffa0629c901d65bb1b.jpeg",
            "width": 284,
            "height": 160,
            "context": "default",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-18T23:02:24+0800",
            "created_at": "2014-04-18T23:02:24+0800",
            "content_type": "image/jpeg",
            "size": 26337,
            "id": 192
        },
        {
            "provider_metadata": {
                "filename": "vr-banner-medium.png"
            },
            "name": "vr-banner-medium.png",
            "enabled": false,
            "provider_name": "sonata.media.provider.image",
            "provider_status": 1,
            "provider_reference": "75ec61e5b12b2d0868886297c073f6228bf9fdcc.png",
            "width": 183,
            "height": 314,
            "context": "default",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-18T23:47:34+0800",
            "created_at": "2014-04-18T23:47:34+0800",
            "content_type": "image/png",
            "size": 87214,
            "id": 193
        },
        {
            "provider_metadata": {
                "filename": "1111.jpg"
            },
            "name": "1111.jpg",
            "enabled": false,
            "provider_name": "sonata.media.provider.image",
            "provider_status": 1,
            "provider_reference": "08ae40d9ef11ce3e6118d172dbffcfba96f282ad.jpeg",
            "width": 284,
            "height": 160,
            "context": "default",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-18T23:48:19+0800",
            "created_at": "2014-04-18T23:48:19+0800",
            "content_type": "image/jpeg",
            "size": 26337,
            "id": 194
        },
        {
            "provider_metadata": {
                "filename": "test.mp3"
            },
            "name": "test.mp3",
            "enabled": false,
            "provider_name": "sonata.media.provider.file",
            "provider_status": 1,
            "provider_reference": "7d0ea143ca408f94633098cd9696fddaba913833.mpga",
            "context": "default",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-18T23:48:19+0800",
            "created_at": "2014-04-18T23:48:19+0800",
            "content_type": "audio/mpeg",
            "size": 198658,
            "id": 195
        },
        {
            "provider_metadata": {
                "filename": "Tulips.jpg"
            },
            "name": "Tulips.jpg",
            "enabled": false,
            "provider_name": "sonata.media.provider.image",
            "provider_status": 1,
            "provider_reference": "62c5aed648c9f1189ee248703550ac2dda7c03e0.jpeg",
            "width": 1024,
            "height": 768,
            "context": "default",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-19T03:08:07+0800",
            "created_at": "2014-04-19T03:08:07+0800",
            "content_type": "image/jpeg",
            "size": 620888,
            "id": 196
        },
        {
            "provider_metadata": {
                "filename": "Jellyfish.jpg"
            },
            "name": "Jellyfish.jpg",
            "enabled": false,
            "provider_name": "sonata.media.provider.image",
            "provider_status": 1,
            "provider_reference": "a4212f424dedc8c6c743cc86a1e30e9eb05ab715.jpeg",
            "width": 1024,
            "height": 768,
            "context": "default",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-19T03:15:26+0800",
            "created_at": "2014-04-19T03:15:26+0800",
            "content_type": "image/jpeg",
            "size": 775702,
            "id": 197
        },
        {
            "provider_metadata": {
                "filename": "Hydrangeas.jpg"
            },
            "name": "Chrysanthemum.jpg",
            "enabled": false,
            "provider_name": "sonata.media.provider.image",
            "provider_status": 1,
            "provider_reference": "74648433c8a402533297fa77ee08afc8d6d68a30.jpeg",
            "width": 1024,
            "height": 768,
            "context": "default",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-19T03:16:23+0800",
            "created_at": "2014-04-19T03:16:03+0800",
            "content_type": "image/jpeg",
            "size": 595284,
            "id": 198
        },
        {
            "provider_metadata": {
                "filename": "Jellyfish.jpg"
            },
            "name": "Chrysanthemum.jpg",
            "enabled": false,
            "provider_name": "sonata.media.provider.image",
            "provider_status": 1,
            "provider_reference": "fa93114359b2a49a81c6885f95e3acde74ee882b.jpeg",
            "width": 1024,
            "height": 768,
            "context": "default",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-19T03:20:23+0800",
            "created_at": "2014-04-19T03:16:53+0800",
            "content_type": "image/jpeg",
            "size": 775702,
            "id": 199
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the response as a `java/lang/String`:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(responseString);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static ArrayList<YourBean> parseJsonObj(Object objPre) {
    ArrayList<YourBean> infos = new ArrayList<YourBean>();
    try {

        if (objPre instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray jsList = (JSONArray) objPre;
            for (int i = 0; i < jsList.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject value = jsList.getJSONObject(i);
                infos.add(parseJson(value));
            }
        } else if (objPre instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) objPre;
            infos.add(parseJson(obj));
        }
        return infos;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return infos;
    }
}

private static YourBean parseJson(JSONObject value)
throws JSONException {
    YourBean info = new YourBean();
    if (value.has("name")) {
        String name = value.getString("name");
        info.setName(name);
    }
    .......
    return info;
}
```