# Parse JSON without key

Tags: android, json

My basic JSON data structure is this:

```
[
  {
    "data1":"contents of data1",
    "data2":"contents of data 2"
  },
  {
    "data1":"contents of data1",
    "data2":"contents of data 2"
  }
]
```

I tried using `JSONArray myJson = new JSONArray(json);`

but it gives me:

> org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class org.json.JSONObject

I am retrieving the JSON through:

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// Getting JSON from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

And convert it to JSONArray using  `JSONArray myJson = new JSONArray(json);`

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JSONArray without array name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164741/get-jsonarray-without-array-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate your json without key as follows

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("[{\"data1\":\"contents of data1\",\"data2\":\"contents of data 2\"},{\"data1\":\"contents of data1\",\"data2\":\"contents of data 2\"}]");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();

        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            System.out.println("Mykey: " + key + " value: " + jsonObject.getString(key));    
        }
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: sorry it was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

**The reason of that error might be invalid json.**

This is how your data2 key - value pair is

```
"data2":contents of data 2"
```

Put the quotes **"** before **contents** and use this

```
"data2":"contents of data 2"
```

Change all occurences of this error and it should work. Do let me know if it changes anything for you.

Comment: sorry it was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

In python, If u have json data as

**data**=[{
     "data1":"contents of data1",
     "data2":"contents of data 2"
   },
   {
     "data1":"contents of data1",
     "data2":"contents of data 2"
   }
]

you can access it using:
print "data1:",**data[0]["data1"]**